# Fetching image from url with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image

I am trying to show an image on my page from a different url.

```
<body>
<div id="container">
    <br />

    <canvas width="500px" height="375px" id="canvas">
    </canvas>
    <img src="http://yinoneliraz-001-site1.smarterasp.net/MyPicture.png" />

</div>
<script>

    var img = new Image;
    img.src = "http://yinoneliraz-001-site1.smarterasp.net/MyPicture.png";

    var timer = setInterval(function () { MyTimer() }, 200);
    function MyTimer() {
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0,500,675);
        img = new Image;
        img.src = "http://yinoneliraz-001-site1.smarterasp.net/MyPicture.png";
    }
</script>
```

The image on the other site is being saved every 1.5 seconds.
The result is that I cant view the image.
Any ideas why?

Thanks!

Comment: Could be an issue with the image cacheing, or your server/client connection speed is not fast enough to download the image before it is deleted and rewritten.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### 1. Cache issue

Your `MyPicture.png` returns `Cache-Control: max-age=31536000` in HTTP response. So browser may get image from its cache on second time. You need to add query string something like thie:

```
img.src = "http://yinoneliraz-001-site1.smarterasp.net/MyPicture.png?time=" + (new Date()).getTime();
```

#### 2. Too short fetching period.

I think fetching period 200msec is too short. It's better to bind `onload` event handler to the image object. See [How to fetch a remote image to display in a canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164181/how-to-fetch-a-remote-image-to-display-in-a-canvas).

```
function copyCanvas(img) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}

function loadImage() {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
        copyCanvas(img);
    };
    img.src = "http://yinoneliraz-001-site1.smarterasp.net/MyPicture.png?time=" + (new Date()).getTime();
}
```

#### 3. Double buffering

I think your script intend to pre-load image. So it's better to make a double buffering.

Single Buffering version: http://jsfiddle.net/tokkonoPapa/dSJmy/1/

Double Buffering version: http://jsfiddle.net/tokkonoPapa/dSJmy/2/

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined `canvas`. Define it first with:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
```

Then, use `load` event to draw image on to the canvas.

Checkout the fiddle, [LoadImgURL](http://jsfiddle.net/AliasM2K/56BTc/) which demonstrates the whole process.