# how to convert an image into base 64 in angular5?

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

how to convert an image into base 64 in angular5 ?
the image is an url gotten from facebook or google authentification api.

what have i done wrong ?

```
   getBase64Image(img) {
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = img.src.width;
canvas.height = img.src.height;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
}
```

// Usage

```
    var url=" https://www.livemint.com/rf/Image-621x414/LiveMint/Period2/2017/06/12/Photos/Opinion/telecom-km8--621x414@LiveMint.JPG";


var base64 = this.getBase64Image(url);
```

//error

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of undefined
```

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Image as `File`, you can easily convert it to base64 by using a FileReader:

```
convert(file: File): string {
    const reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = (): void => {
        const base64String: string = (reader.result as string).match(
            /.+;base64,(.+)/
        )[1];
        return base64String;
    };
}
```

Comment: Hey i have the image as an url

Comment: Then you will have to request it from the URL before you can save its base64 string

Comment: sorry by how can i do it ?

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18417691/fetching-image-from-url-with-javascript?lq=1