# Extracting RGB channel from an image

Tags: javascript, image-processing

Is it possible to extract the colors from an image of any type using javascript? i want the percentage of each color in the image as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the base 64 encoded image data,

```
function getBase64FromImage(img) {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;

    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    return canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
}
```

You'll probably want to have a library process the image data, rather than doing it yourself:

[What is the best JavaScript image processing library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351122/what-is-the-best-javascript-image-processing-library)

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible. You need to load the image on a canvas. Then you can extract the color on each arbitrary x,y coordinate.

You might want to have a look at

- http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/color-thief/
- [getPixel from HTML Canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667045/getpixel-from-html-canvas)
- [How to fetch a remote image to display in a canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164181/how-to-fetch-a-remote-image-to-display-in-a-canvas)
- [How to add image to canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011378/how-to-add-image-to-canvas)